# CloudStack installation: Error creating instance

Tags: centos6.4, cloudstack

I am a newbie to CloudStack. I installed it using Quick Install Guide on CentOS 6.4 and kvm. As my network is a LAN at my faculty and there is a DHCP and Gateway for connecting to internet, at the beginning I defined address pool of Pod and guest withing the range of LAN addresses. But I wasn't able to create instances getting this error:

```
2013-06-17 13:44:03,445 DEBUG [cloud.storage.StorageManagerImpl] (Job-Executor-1:job-9) Insufficient un-allocated capacity on: 200 for volume allocation: [Vol[3|vm=3|ROOT]] since its allocated percentage: 2.2468850974329963E7 has crossed the allocated pool.storage.allocated.capacity.disablethreshold: 0.85, skipping this pool
```

I guessed this is because of IP conflicts between pool and dhcp range. So I re-installed it (removed and re-installed cloud-agent and cloud-client), and this time defined a different subnet for address pools (255.0.0.0) from dhcp subnet (255.255.0.0). But now I'm getting this error while "Creating system VMs" after doing the configuration using UI:

```
WARN  [cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl] (consoleproxy-1:) Exception while trying to start console proxy
com.cloud.exception.AgentUnavailableException: Resource [Host:1] is unreachable: Host 1: Unable to start instance due to Unable to start VM[ConsoleProxy|v-2-VM] due to error in finalizeStart, not retrying
    at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.advanceStart(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:847)
    at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.start(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:472)
    at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.start(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:465)
    at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.startProxy(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:627)
    at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.allocCapacity(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:1164)
    at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.expandPool(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:1981)
    at com.cloud.consoleproxy.ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.expandPool(ConsoleProxyManagerImpl.java:173)
    at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner.loadScan(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:113)
    at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner.access$100(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:34)
    at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner$1.reallyRun(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:83)
    at com.cloud.vm.SystemVmLoadScanner$1.run(SystemVmLoadScanner.java:73)
    at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:471)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRunAndReset(FutureTask.java:351)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.access$301(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:178)
    at java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:293)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
Caused by: com.cloud.utils.exception.ExecutionException: Unable to start VM[ConsoleProxy|v-2-VM] due to error in finalizeStart, not retrying
    at com.cloud.vm.VirtualMachineManagerImpl.advanceStart(VirtualMachineManagerImpl.java:814)
    ... 19 more
```

Is the problem related to IP conflict? If yes, how to solve it?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The error message says

> [cloud.storage.StorageManagerImpl] (Job-Executor-1:job-9) Insufficient
>   un-allocated capacity on: 200 for volume allocation:
>   [Vol[3|vm=3|ROOT]] since its allocated percentage:
>   2.2468850974329963E7 has crossed the allocated pool.storage.allocated.capacity.disable

It's talking about storage space/disk space, not IP addresses. You need to check your settings for allocated spacfe and required free disk space.

Comment: thanks for replying. I have almost 150 GB free on primary and secondary storage. Is it not enough for 1 instance?

Comment: The error message says clearly that there is `insufficient un-allocated capacity on 200 for volume allocation`. So something in your settings is making it impossible to allocate the volume. I can't say any more than that without seeing the actual settings.

Comment: ok. thanks. I'm gonna install it again as I didn't find the exact problem. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

It is talking about storage space/disk space, not an IP address. You need to check your settings for the allocated space and the required free disk space.
I think you need more that 100GB.